# ggplot with gapminder data

Tags: r, ggplot2

New to R, trying to cleanup [gapminder data](http://www.gapminder.org/data/) - *Energy use, per person*.

Running into some problems, after my initial cleanup. I'm stuck. Unable to generate desired graph, like which should be the x, and which should be the y if I want all the country on the graph.

Code so far:

```
library(xlsx)
energy.pp <- read.xlsx("energypp.xlsx", sheetName = "Data", )

names(energy.pp)[names(energy.pp) == 'Energy.use..per.capita..toe.'] <- "country"

energy.pp2 <- na.omit(energy.pp)

energy.pp2$country

energy.pp3 <- t(energy.pp2)
energy.pp3 <- as.data.frame(energy.pp3)
```

Current data frame:
dupe(head(energy.pp3))

```
structure(list(`14` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", 
"X1960", "X1961", "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 3.0635543", 
" 3.1157871", " 3.1729749", " 3.2840510", " 3.3494142", " 3.4632156", 
" 3.5465380", " 3.6928079", " 3.7635584", " 3.7929348", " 3.9896297", 
" 4.0352063", " 4.0634114", " 4.2642712", " 4.2941616", " 4.3458714", 
" 4.4057030", " 4.6296185", " 4.6711957", " 4.6838532", " 5.295940", 
" 5.447417", " 5.514906", " 5.570153", " 5.573862", " 5.593221", 
" 5.600235", " 5.605497", " 5.610887", " 5.644541", " 5.683007", 
" 5.738863", " 5.778817", "4.561426", "4.6204518", "4.6214209", 
"4.651519", "4.6946764", "4.7374820", "4.7649451", "4.7707422", 
"4.817490", "4.9268353", "4.9575237", "4.9980473", "5.0527697", 
"5.1112486", "5.121670", "5.1607065", "5.403657", "5.470088", 
"5.554760", "Australia"), class = "factor"), `15` = structure(c(53L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
"X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.5462615", " 1.5540349", 
" 1.6758736", " 1.8239952", " 1.8518436", " 1.8550852", " 1.9027564", 
" 1.9202121", " 2.0458281", " 2.1816323", " 2.4182101", " 2.5085209", 
" 2.6273225", " 2.6548487", " 2.7304373", " 2.7974219", " 2.8309468", 
" 2.8669759", " 2.8930223", " 3.1389161", " 3.564578", " 3.585109", 
" 3.752244", " 3.767459", " 3.796843", " 3.875007", " 3.966704", 
" 4.000780", " 4.022449", " 4.023801", " 4.033582", " 4.085860", 
" 4.103304", "2.830222", "2.843406", "2.8970094", "2.953688", 
"3.0515971", "3.0615889", "3.0670119", "3.1389835", "3.1747454", 
"3.2045622", "3.2296387", "3.2355392", "3.2403617", "3.2503975", 
"3.368098", "3.4099483", "3.544437", "3.573954", "3.600872", 
"Austria"), class = "factor"), `22` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 4L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", "X1962", 
"X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 2.5191590", " 2.5705320", " 2.8097311", 
" 3.0217114", " 3.0432207", " 3.0513032", " 3.1160160", " 3.1829235", 
" 3.5900043", " 3.8770444", " 4.0999553", " 4.1351998", " 4.3179357", 
" 4.4739295", " 4.5895244", " 4.6174986", " 4.6222331", " 4.7207841", 
" 4.8271368", " 4.9766855", " 5.082476", " 5.288913", " 5.366718", 
" 5.454730", " 5.469582", " 5.509344", " 5.585584", " 5.600428", 
" 5.650965", " 5.673903", " 5.688972", " 5.707434", " 5.709104", 
"4.156368", "4.207902", "4.335818", "4.4153622", "4.4734737", 
"4.6338730", "4.7285033", "4.7435750", "4.7712763", "4.7986932", 
"4.8441858", "4.9542909", "5.0559004", "5.0929468", "5.2254116", 
"5.304052", "5.579511", "5.586789", "5.659692", "Belgium"), class = "factor"), 
    `38` = structure(c(52L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", 
    "X1960", "X1961", "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 4.2512100", 
    " 4.3078208", " 4.4515601", " 4.6941201", " 4.9036076", " 5.1539324", 
    " 5.2726647", " 5.5572917", " 5.8715204", " 6.0911000", " 6.4763885", 
    " 6.5303355", " 6.9336066", " 7.1005480", " 7.1233794", " 7.1501068", 
    " 7.2725500", " 7.379626", " 7.4095300", " 7.426204", " 7.433974", 
    " 7.5388429", " 7.8377697", " 7.914379", " 7.945846", " 7.975109", 
    " 8.010802", " 8.171665", " 8.236770", " 8.251850", " 8.272314", 
    " 8.364289", " 8.424041", "7.052768", "7.160591", "7.342138", 
    "7.3889581", "7.4395929", "7.4801406", "7.4925874", "7.5039574", 
    "7.5422707", "7.6416879", "7.8318537", "7.8343193", "7.837739", 
    "7.8555363", "7.861733", "7.9341150", "7.956702", "7.965586", 
    "Canada"), class = "factor"), `60` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.9229737", " 2.0233084", 
    " 2.2962896", " 2.5029276", " 2.6001558", " 2.8227348", " 3.0611101", 
    " 3.0674278", " 3.141668", " 3.2037523", " 3.322982", " 3.4532072", 
    " 3.470399", " 3.485343", " 3.4896065", " 3.489699", " 3.495099", 
    " 3.535165", " 3.583440", " 3.594966", " 3.602700", " 3.618512", 
    " 3.6995304", " 3.724567", " 3.726408", " 3.7285380", " 3.7455618", 
    " 3.7817572", " 3.8301038", " 3.8585921", " 3.8946378", " 3.9714307", 
    " 4.0200365", "3.233160", "3.353461", "3.3774805", "3.3814345", 
    "3.4142512", "3.422375", "3.5620861", "3.6420037", "3.6457019", 
    "3.705398", "3.7350776", "3.7351441", "3.7595191", "3.772290", 
    "3.7741121", "3.8198296", "3.8234799", "3.848241", "4.170031", 
    "Denmark"), class = "factor"), `76` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 2.1969531", " 2.2527787", 
    " 2.3617439", " 2.4789120", " 2.6783832", " 2.8876941", " 3.0654387", 
    " 3.1264260", " 3.3427033", " 3.6685233", " 3.8722230", " 3.9392111", 
    " 4.1818107", " 4.1881607", " 4.3838481", " 4.4598596", " 4.5075570", 
    " 4.5162481", " 4.6645232", " 4.9635355", " 6.226394", " 6.227018", 
    " 6.283958", " 6.358825", " 6.389240", " 6.529459", " 6.638823", 
    " 6.694238", " 6.787212", " 6.957265", " 7.047664", " 7.086904", 
    " 7.098453", "4.805494", "4.823859", "4.910523", "4.9345885", 
    "5.1466423", "5.2698924", "5.3809931", "5.4825784", "5.5904365", 
    "5.6172154", "5.661904", "5.6915712", "5.7427842", "5.7536393", 
    "5.9606926", "5.9725543", "6.070212", "6.276952", "6.319327", 
    "Finland"), class = "factor"), `77` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.6995421", " 1.7446649", 
    " 1.8605248", " 1.9829629", " 2.0846903", " 2.1094591", " 2.1226233", 
    " 2.2478905", " 2.3598112", " 2.5366883", " 2.9515617", " 3.0278889", 
    " 3.0584630", " 3.1707310", " 3.1726381", " 3.2474818", " 3.2530881", 
    " 3.3692350", " 3.3853619", " 3.4957776", " 3.842635", " 3.916691", 
    " 4.030517", " 4.113622", " 4.116148", " 4.120953", " 4.135012", 
    " 4.191468", " 4.224798", " 4.242844", " 4.270583", " 4.283718", 
    " 4.301043", "3.279197", "3.346066", "3.3785479", "3.446328", 
    "3.4762369", "3.5949360", "3.6303915", "3.6628785", "3.6993589", 
    "3.7934190", "3.8357354", "3.8419093", "3.9530035", "3.973845", 
    "4.0026912", "4.035813", "4.0405288", "4.140963", "4.180983", 
    "France"), class = "factor"), `83` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.9525339", " 1.9943206", 
    " 2.1248258", " 2.2812875", " 2.3411590", " 2.3783503", " 2.3877098", 
    " 2.3884108", " 2.5615208", " 2.7720082", " 3.758410", " 3.8608649", 
    " 3.871738", " 3.8952647", " 3.9849742", " 4.003264", " 4.0173374", 
    " 4.025570", " 4.068954", " 4.079709", " 4.094125", " 4.101618", 
    " 4.104246", " 4.135561", " 4.135783", " 4.1582716", " 4.159426", 
    " 4.209827", " 4.2400619", " 4.3145816", " 4.3360874", " 4.4838808", 
    " 4.6852967", "4.0877159", "4.119871", "4.1219140", "4.177370", 
    "4.1901146", "4.203397", "4.245936", "4.257864", "4.268263", 
    "4.3025533", "4.3994998", "4.4206451", "4.446685", "4.5148590", 
    "4.5622960", "4.5892293", "4.5981413", "4.6163703", "4.6292645", 
    "Germany"), class = "factor"), `86` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 0.2890571", " 0.3224906", 
    " 0.3501013", " 0.3678114", " 0.4335593", " 0.4787559", " 0.5471970", 
    " 0.6077022", " 0.6520816", " 0.7255256", " 0.8727837", " 0.9840421", 
    " 1.1347865", " 1.2563487", " 1.2982044", " 1.3227639", " 1.3861005", 
    " 1.4695494", " 1.5254435", " 1.5979259", " 2.348195", " 2.363534", 
    " 2.440492", " 2.481000", " 2.557434", " 2.577529", " 2.608921", 
    " 2.643513", " 2.685582", " 2.699663", " 2.706980", " 2.710933", 
    " 2.724029", "1.5052794", "1.537278", "1.5537816", "1.599084", 
    "1.652822", "1.6738193", "1.7667533", "1.7918052", "1.9029031", 
    "2.0897158", "2.0931142", "2.1076334", "2.1109346", "2.1301243", 
    "2.132552", "2.1359323", "2.185427", "2.257732", "2.364567", 
    "Greece"), class = "factor"), `101` = structure(c(53L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 2.9167062", " 3.0282984", 
    " 3.0827116", " 3.2796023", " 3.3068160", " 3.4445513", " 3.5534767", 
    " 3.5943618", " 3.6397709", " 3.9241344", " 4.2319921", " 4.3783103", 
    " 4.4039696", " 5.0716353", " 5.0855810", " 5.1321971", " 5.2689657", 
    " 5.6028702", " 5.7107101", " 6.5150597", "10.670540", "11.023165", 
    "11.305961", "11.363581", "11.423796", "11.531687", "11.729269", 
    "13.690215", "15.522149", "16.868468", "16.882499", "16.904904", 
    "17.983310", "6.5609982", "7.076208", "7.1788694", "7.254286", 
    "7.3349019", "7.531270", "7.6055638", "7.7925625", "7.8574549", 
    "7.8824738", "7.9543439", "7.9830375", "8.1957100", "8.2084347", 
    "8.2671267", "8.421591", "8.873656", "8.952650", "9.407999", 
    "Iceland"), class = "factor"), `106` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 6L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.3188125", " 1.3964662", 
    " 1.4127297", " 1.4539621", " 1.5119049", " 1.5221950", " 1.6295919", 
    " 1.7674251", " 1.8811494", " 1.9745889", " 2.0236311", " 2.0839949", 
    " 2.1101919", " 2.1787210", " 2.1945131", " 2.2038215", " 2.2384718", 
    " 2.2453234", " 2.2680899", " 2.5343386", " 3.011987", " 3.217686", 
    " 3.229943", " 3.379305", " 3.463176", " 3.464668", " 3.479163", 
    " 3.545371", " 3.588298", " 3.596080", " 3.608370", " 3.704764", 
    " 3.747932", "2.336185", "2.346152", "2.356894", "2.3929540", 
    "2.4131564", "2.4387323", "2.5043196", "2.5934781", "2.6078891", 
    "2.6550359", "2.7778234", "2.8181330", "2.8338285", "2.8422444", 
    "2.9456014", "2.946812", "3.136458", "3.253814", "3.430681", 
    "Ireland"), class = "factor"), `109` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 0.7948206", " 0.8906803", 
    " 1.0070452", " 1.1197295", " 1.2217317", " 1.3164642", " 1.4310759", 
    " 1.5515192", " 1.6984276", " 1.8324999", " 1.9491487", " 2.0262175", 
    " 2.0507379", " 2.1060787", " 2.1755875", " 2.2041798", " 2.2122067", 
    " 2.2475655", " 2.2640572", " 2.3400420", " 2.717429", " 2.738843", 
    " 2.814639", " 2.941636", " 2.957316", " 3.012219", " 3.016166", 
    " 3.021249", " 3.024804", " 3.084926", " 3.114726", " 3.128308", 
    " 3.137385", "2.203864", "2.206543", "2.253719", "2.2659311", 
    "2.2848113", "2.3115481", "2.3184273", "2.4072564", "2.4627968", 
    "2.5661089", "2.5784726", "2.5838881", "2.6119904", "2.6273381", 
    "2.6456732", "2.796157", "2.799413", "2.834388", "2.912932", 
    "Italy"), class = "factor"), `111` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 0.8739103", " 0.9629071", 
    " 1.0037523", " 1.1364849", " 1.2604745", " 1.3615872", " 1.4769975", 
    " 1.7205497", " 1.9384568", " 2.1936101", " 2.4583571", " 2.5310885", 
    " 2.6670467", " 2.7251593", " 2.8768009", " 2.8983388", " 2.8999042", 
    " 2.9242457", " 2.9642082", " 3.0440528", " 3.584391", " 3.701072", 
    " 3.878907", " 3.898371", " 3.963719", " 4.004815", " 4.017295", 
    " 4.032163", " 4.045481", " 4.068745", " 4.073946", " 4.089581", 
    " 4.090515", "2.823858", "2.840614", "2.8642774", "2.9501353", 
    "3.0053055", "3.017806", "3.0207226", "3.0442267", "3.2426410", 
    "3.3506743", "3.5562238", "3.5835746", "3.6586664", "3.6741479", 
    "3.8676069", "3.956198", "3.981269", "4.032119", "4.064345", 
    "Japan"), class = "factor"), `131` = structure(c(53L, 21L, 
    22L, 16L, 18L, 27L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 7.258837", " 7.617914", 
    " 7.931542", " 7.938957", " 8.027161", " 8.154173", " 8.342547", 
    " 8.499666", " 8.609796", " 8.767505", " 9.179768", " 9.331423", 
    " 9.433496", "10.2785576", "10.3619726", "10.4145409", "10.4581129", 
    "10.4658130", "10.4806062", "10.5049812", "10.5234067", "10.5340182", 
    "10.6685674", "10.9263952", "11.0960037", "11.1146673", "11.1500503", 
    "11.8630896", "11.9741926", "12.0095701", "12.1061529", "12.6485604", 
    "13.0238896", "7.067874", "7.417771", "7.576207", "7.711006", 
    "7.732638", "7.9429481", "8.057810", "8.112675", "8.1584335", 
    "8.1635488", "8.3469264", "8.5260374", "8.6999364", "8.9124651", 
    "8.9318581", "9.3426149", "9.3464847", "9.4120904", "9.7746506", 
    "Luxembourg"), class = "factor"), `158` = structure(c(53L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.8257353", " 1.8789751", 
    " 2.0809654", " 2.2684264", " 2.3491488", " 2.4931923", " 2.6055591", 
    " 2.7627289", " 3.0427434", " 3.3627486", " 3.7655650", " 3.8553104", 
    " 4.3187277", " 4.3810065", " 4.5013526", " 4.519164", " 4.5602752", 
    " 4.597828", " 4.6132105", " 4.644802", " 4.6626053", " 4.687982", 
    " 4.700183", " 4.712300", " 4.729160", " 4.7429799", " 4.807931", 
    " 4.829936", " 4.837167", " 4.843796", " 4.856639", " 4.8686356", 
    " 5.020998", "3.785116", "3.935957", "4.147702", "4.1844298", 
    "4.2694141", "4.3173156", "4.3211005", "4.3238582", "4.3876707", 
    "4.3932037", "4.5016609", "4.5084596", "4.5094687", "4.5488248", 
    "4.576470", "4.579475", "4.599694", "4.6026436", "4.728194", 
    "Netherlands"), class = "factor"), `161` = structure(c(53L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.7314654", " 1.8084444", 
    " 1.8200077", " 1.9670539", " 2.2088807", " 2.2174016", " 2.2747032", 
    " 2.3203853", " 2.3398315", " 2.4086891", " 2.4226803", " 2.4925994", 
    " 2.6497524", " 2.7081029", " 2.8344580", " 2.8389475", " 2.9581807", 
    " 2.9966523", " 3.0317993", " 3.1249955", " 4.044953", " 4.049826", 
    " 4.054330", " 4.075089", " 4.079142", " 4.086158", " 4.166425", 
    " 4.183351", " 4.255055", " 4.313227", " 4.335665", " 4.412003", 
    " 4.422104", "2.8499856", "2.8863240", "3.012971", "3.076830", 
    "3.251076", "3.4483284", "3.4525257", "3.4640960", "3.6087988", 
    "3.7709882", "3.8111553", "3.8467386", "3.8646168", "3.9864397", 
    "4.0267041", "4.053385", "4.141267", "4.155024", "4.251905", 
    "New Zealand"), class = "factor"), `170` = structure(c(53L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.9061749", " 1.9376447", 
    " 2.0520545", " 2.1829931", " 2.3200131", " 2.5395977", " 2.7100782", 
    " 2.8156880", " 3.0528966", " 3.1936551", " 3.4070623", " 3.4176747", 
    " 3.4959603", " 3.5729755", " 3.6003827", " 3.6423671", " 3.9518967", 
    " 4.0496403", " 4.3505852", " 4.4577167", " 5.489420", " 5.756449", 
    " 5.787937", " 5.809789", " 5.817682", " 5.831168", " 5.849374", 
    " 5.896889", " 5.919067", " 5.942570", " 6.032853", " 6.250025", 
    " 6.637364", "4.254671", "4.4064515", "4.419380", "4.4831644", 
    "4.663362", "4.8061720", "4.8071934", "4.9517095", "4.9725773", 
    "5.0154650", "5.0376416", "5.0903428", "5.1434355", "5.186666", 
    "5.2987094", "5.377081", "5.4432516", "5.461541", "5.668475", 
    "Norway"), class = "factor"), `180` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.8279756", " 1.8941026", 
    " 1.9768342", " 1.9842243", " 2.0315942", " 2.0880150", " 2.1408930", 
    " 2.1990422", " 2.2902291", " 2.317484", " 2.324202", " 2.346068", 
    " 2.384658", " 2.393027", " 2.405230", " 2.420429", " 2.4383554", 
    " 2.463505", " 2.539933", " 2.549495", " 2.5500041", " 2.567613", 
    " 2.6270663", " 2.657011", " 2.685342", " 2.6938185", " 2.7843561", 
    " 2.8821964", " 3.0294093", " 3.1579420", " 3.2518106", " 3.4884057", 
    " 3.5653301", "2.469766", "2.4958420", "2.5691129", "2.577317", 
    "2.6245475", "2.6409244", "2.641706", "2.679012", "2.7053915", 
    "3.211684", "3.2453115", "3.2592346", "3.350915", "3.3519279", 
    "3.412508", "3.4642599", "3.4969900", "3.5355093", "3.5593257", 
    "Poland"), class = "factor"), `181` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 0.3369136", " 0.3631640", 
    " 0.3658401", " 0.3949390", " 0.4102518", " 0.4408829", " 0.4517508", 
    " 0.4865854", " 0.4971290", " 0.5799725", " 0.6638615", " 0.7260505", 
    " 0.7452840", " 0.7988352", " 0.8243612", " 0.8453624", " 0.8453689", 
    " 0.8723494", " 0.9167694", " 0.9981607", " 2.176045", " 2.213051", 
    " 2.271502", " 2.299879", " 2.333477", " 2.385064", " 2.406715", 
    " 2.409960", " 2.410818", " 2.412805", " 2.459618", " 2.490622", 
    " 2.508875", "1.0064941", "1.0224636", "1.0938586", "1.115894", 
    "1.117913", "1.119205", "1.2084743", "1.2411957", "1.2995851", 
    "1.5757545", "1.6767444", "1.7000527", "1.7793362", "1.8078251", 
    "1.8223229", "1.992940", "2.015020", "2.092466", "2.254811", 
    "Portugal"), class = "factor"), `213` = structure(c(53L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 0.5308377", " 0.5575993", 
    " 0.6052235", " 0.6235182", " 0.6836856", " 0.7147216", " 0.7907917", 
    " 0.8813832", " 0.9936646", " 1.0497912", " 1.1231030", " 1.2460979", 
    " 1.2994310", " 1.4812286", " 1.5899696", " 1.6180208", " 1.6676460", 
    " 1.7173132", " 1.7570337", " 1.7683286", " 2.723007", " 2.772667", 
    " 2.776293", " 2.911279", " 3.029303", " 3.051899", " 3.070927", 
    " 3.120079", " 3.172161", " 3.204822", " 3.212914", " 3.257794", 
    " 3.269025", "1.762405", "1.783766", "1.8081048", "1.815878", 
    "1.8209758", "1.8457113", "1.8781644", "1.9193417", "2.0679047", 
    "2.2717510", "2.3187608", "2.3290190", "2.3996384", "2.4350187", 
    "2.4516558", "2.515802", "2.559006", "2.667652", "2.791281", 
    "Spain"), class = "factor"), `219` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 2.6987923", " 2.7421235", 
    " 2.8872363", " 3.0804141", " 3.2735090", " 3.4375408", " 3.6301941", 
    " 3.6366439", " 4.0008233", " 4.3032239", " 4.4503825", " 4.5104430", 
    " 4.5272137", " 4.6812998", " 4.7644990", " 4.7738114", " 4.883200", 
    " 5.0167891", " 5.0548338", " 5.1512514", " 5.225873", " 5.2296075", 
    " 5.360145", " 5.379959", " 5.468217", " 5.472135", " 5.529078", 
    " 5.650438", " 5.661520", " 5.680280", " 5.711127", " 5.802110", 
    " 5.847344", "4.8715837", "4.877774", "4.941260", "5.0971543", 
    "5.216251", "5.3340938", "5.3695849", "5.5145501", "5.5945470", 
    "5.6507739", "5.6561872", "5.6601072", "5.672034", "5.702172", 
    "5.7634561", "5.769687", "5.824991", "5.8544182", "5.8787874", 
    "Sweden"), class = "factor"), `220` = structure(c(53L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 1.3986548", " 1.4547551", 
    " 1.5689111", " 1.8194353", " 1.8695875", " 1.9436005", " 1.9666921", 
    " 2.0408279", " 2.1726039", " 2.3344440", " 2.5566587", " 2.6376708", 
    " 2.7107729", " 2.7277192", " 2.7835145", " 2.8210129", " 2.8777929", 
    " 2.9950168", " 2.9980052", " 3.0421792", " 3.227096", " 3.348752", 
    " 3.412123", " 3.481487", " 3.483225", " 3.488805", " 3.501334", 
    " 3.531475", " 3.543079", " 3.548322", " 3.554391", " 3.619761", 
    " 3.674225", "2.984223", "3.0933233", "3.1705755", "3.173308", 
    "3.239370", "3.3390835", "3.4123911", "3.416948", "3.4308555", 
    "3.4368758", "3.467910", "3.4844883", "3.4901928", "3.527224", 
    "3.5445221", "3.559098", "3.6062438", "3.6214060", "3.6280178", 
    "Switzerland"), class = "factor"), `233` = structure(c(53L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 0.3754994", " 0.3796039", 
    " 0.4000097", " 0.4098690", " 0.4218366", " 0.4337864", " 0.4659317", 
    " 0.4724597", " 0.4863004", " 0.5018974", " 0.5135428", " 0.5392001", 
    " 0.5956838", " 0.6428653", " 0.6507402", " 0.6759066", " 0.7011903", 
    " 0.7198797", " 0.7536706", " 0.7728543", " 1.090740", " 1.122560", 
    " 1.134488", " 1.173258", " 1.199918", " 1.202597", " 1.238262", 
    " 1.347093", " 1.359302", " 1.388840", " 1.428791", " 1.445082", 
    " 1.550560", "0.7026108", "0.7129472", "0.729498", "0.754579", 
    "0.767443", "0.7958696", "0.8405481", "0.9050483", "0.9135867", 
    "0.9228069", "0.9458874", "0.9584222", "0.9704462", "0.9746126", 
    "0.9987848", "1.045536", "1.118913", "1.159549", "1.160979", 
    "Turkey"), class = "factor"), `240` = structure(c(53L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 6L, 7L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 3.0066842", " 3.017258", 
    " 3.0327797", " 3.0873791", " 3.188321", " 3.1968312", " 3.2125346", 
    " 3.254089", " 3.3067816", " 3.3294102", " 3.3455535", " 3.394364", 
    " 3.4061445", " 3.459246", " 3.5458171", " 3.5571293", " 3.613890", 
    " 3.6169755", " 3.6754353", " 3.682234", " 3.6849524", " 3.692301", 
    " 3.6953839", " 3.706627", " 3.731118", " 3.7332830", " 3.7348417", 
    " 3.7479625", " 3.783755", " 3.785477", " 3.785789", " 3.8589760", 
    " 3.8806502", "3.366688", "3.378276", "3.398239", "3.4161997", 
    "3.5236488", "3.5505569", "3.5970067", "3.5982443", "3.6187321", 
    "3.6262202", "3.6432571", "3.6854861", "3.7081109", "3.7121741", 
    "3.727464", "3.7291194", "3.759676", "3.786860", "3.878058", 
    "United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), `241` = structure(c(53L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Names = c("country", "X1960", "X1961", 
    "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), .Label = c(" 5.6120527", " 5.6417348", 
    " 5.7746131", " 5.9867949", " 6.1369608", " 6.3078975", " 6.5913380", 
    " 6.8098580", " 7.057277", " 7.069233", " 7.0734738", " 7.164462", 
    " 7.3323664", " 7.487930", " 7.5690887", " 7.6445259", " 7.6562636", 
    " 7.697188", " 7.758206", " 7.794173", " 7.828280", " 7.843393", 
    " 7.846805", " 7.881754", " 7.9095865", " 7.923247", " 7.9410058", 
    " 8.056820", " 8.1005622", " 8.1636038", " 8.2855709", " 8.3270417", 
    " 8.4384031", "7.199305", "7.259079", "7.3759886", "7.443205", 
    "7.4565870", "7.6222276", "7.6315214", "7.6475381", "7.6715540", 
    "7.6773945", "7.7098355", "7.7571398", "7.763365", "7.803655", 
    "7.828535", "7.844015", "7.8499677", "7.8899965", "7.9422530", 
    "United States"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("14", "15", 
"22", "38", "60", "76", "77", "83", "86", "101", "106", "109", 
"111", "131", "158", "161", "170", "180", "181", "213", "219", 
"220", "233", "240", "241"), row.names = c("country", "X1960", 
"X1961", "X1962", "X1963", "X1964"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A picture of your data, that's new one for me. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to provide a reproducible example and properly include data.

Comment: @Florian thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
allCountries <- gather(energy.pp2, year, energy, X1960:X2011)

# create factor variables
allCountries$country.fac <- as.factor(allCountries$country)
allCountries$year.fac <- as.factor(allCountries$year)

ggplot(allCountries, aes(x = year.fac, y = energy)) +
  geom_boxplot(color = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

learned **as.factor** operation, was able to transform the data much better now.

[image]